# How can I contruct dynamic html table having child rows in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, html-table

I am getting data in dataset from sql database and I need to construct dynamic html table having child rows or child grids or child html tables as shown in the image attached. Please help, when the user clicks on the link in the first column child rows should be expanded if it has data othewise it should not show. thanks in advance.
[Please refer this image so that you can have idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddQq6.png)

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: My finger salutes u